# Stuck at "Loading Windows" or any other operating system

Tags: linux, windows, boot, installation

A computer I'm trying to fix gets stuck whenever I try to load an operating system from hard disk or cd-rom.

Originally the system didn't send out a video signal, so I figured the motherboard was broken (as it was an integrated graphics adapter). I ordered a new motherboard online for the same socket and after installing it, the system gave video signal again. However, when I tried to boot, the system got stuck at the "Loading Windows" screen.

Things I have tried to no avail:

- Start the computer normally (Stuck at "Loading Windows")
- Start the computer in safe mode (Stuck at loading "disk.sys")
- Start the computer with an Ubuntu 14.04 Live CD (Cursor keeps flickering, OS doesn't load)
- Run Memtest86+ (It ran for 30 minutes without any problems)
- Run Windows XP Mini from Hiren's Boot CD (Black screen after "Loading system files")
- Start the Windows CD for installation or repair (Stuck at "Loading Windows" after "Loading System  Files")
- Boot from another HDD (Stuck at "Loading Windows")
- Boot with a dedicated graphics card in the PCI-express port (same problems as above)
- Connect the HDD to another computer through USB interface (It loaded in the OS and I could browse the filesystem and take a backup)
- HDD on USB chkcdisk (Fixed some errors)

Other possibly helpful information:

- The BIOS is on the latest version
- The motherboard is a new one
- A disk check turned up with no bad sectors
- There are 3 "Life critical" S.M.A.R.T warnings on the hard drive (Tresh / Value)

  - Raw Read Error Rate (51 / 200)
  - Spin Up Time (21 / 137)
  - Real Located Sector Count (140 / 200)

System specifications:

- AMD Athlon II X2 250 3.0 GHz
- MSI 760GM-P23 (FX)
- 1x 4096MB DDR3 1333MHz
- Western Digital Blue 500GB
- LC Power 420 Watt  PSU

Any ideas on what might be the problem, or tips for more troubleshooting are greatly appreciated.

Edit 1: Added S.M.A.R.T messages

Comment: If you remove the HDD completely and boot from an Ubuntu Live Disc, does it load?

Comment: After choosing the option "Try Ubuntu without installing" the screen turned black and the white cursor keeps flashing at the top left of the screen.

Comment: What are the warnings exactly

Comment: Edited the OP with these warnings.